Unable to push files to iOS simulator using Appium - ApplicationLookupFailed error
I'm encountering issues while trying to push files to an iOS simulator using Appium for test automation. Despite having UIFileSharingEnabled set to true in Info.plist, I'm getting an ApplicationLookupFailed error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to vend into the application documents. Error: ApplicationLookupFailed.
I've tried multiple approaches including: using different path formats (@bundleId:Documents/, Documents/, and full paths), converting files to base64 before pushing, verifying bundle ID and capabilities, and using XCUITest's mobile commands (mobile: pushFile). I've also confirmed the app is properly installed and activated before attempting the file transfer. None of these solutions have resolved the issue - they either result in the same error or silently fail without pushing the file. Has anyone successfully implemented file pushing to iOS simulators with Appium, or found a workaround for this error?
Here is the function I am using to push the files to the simulator:
   public byte[] pushFileToIOSDevice(String imagePath) {
        // Construct the remote path on the iOS device
        String remotePath = "@com.lambdatest.proverbial:Documents/" + new File(imagePath).getName();
        try {
            // Push the file to the iOS device
            driver.pushFile(remotePath, new File(imagePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Throw a RuntimeException if an IOException occurs
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // Retrieve the file from the iOS device as a byte array
        byte[] fileBase64 = driver.pullFile(remotePath);
        // Print the byte array to the console
        System.out.println("Byte value of file: " + Arrays.toString(fileBase64));
        // Return the byte array
        return fileBase64;
    }


